# ASP.NET MVC placing AllowAnonymous attribute dynamically

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, authorization

So I have a custom authorization attribute and some logic inside it. But I am getting circular redirects on one of the actions because of my logic... My question is if it is possible to add somehow an AllowAnonymous attribute inside my redirect?

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "Login" }));
```

Comment: can you not just put the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute on whatever controller action you're trying to redirect to which you want to allow non authenticated users access to?

Comment: @GregH nop my logic insists on placing it dynamically, is that possible?

Comment: Not that I know of. It seems like there are better ways to handle this anyway. if it really needs to be conditionally set, then one possible workaround would be to conditionally pass a routeparam along with the `RedirectToAction` that the specific controller action could check and conditionally permit non authenticated users